# Can't Connect to BigTable using Connection Factory

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-bigtable, hbase-client

I am using a custom code to load HFiles directly into BigTable using the following API's
`LoadIncrementalHFiles loader = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(conf);
loader.doBulkLoad(new Path(inputPath), admin, table, regionLocator);`
while using ConnectionFactory I am using the following function in the statement

```
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf, null, null);
```

which always returns the parameter `managed` as `false` but I am getting the following error while running it.

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.getConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.initialize(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.<init>(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:144)
        at com.example.bigtable.sample.BigtableLoader.main(BigtableLoader.java:122)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
        at com.example.bigtable.sample.BigtableDriver.main(BigtableDriver.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:424)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.shim.HadoopRunJarShim.main(HadoopRunJarShim.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bigtable does not support managed connections.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:130)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection.<init>(BigtableConnection.java:55)
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: Perhaps see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011467/cant-connect-to-bigtable-to-scan-htable-data-due-to-hardcoded-managed-true-in-h

Comment: thanks @Binary Nerd I had seen this page before but couldn't resolve my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Bigtable does not support LoadIncrementalHFiles.  If you want to load data, your best bet is to use [these instructions.](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/importing-sequence-files)

Comment: Hi,
is there any possible way by which i can load csv files directly into Cloud Bigtable?

Comment: We don't have a quick way to do it, but it would be possible to write a Dataflow job that loads the CSV file.